# MEAN Node JS requests intercourse at many requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

I have a MEAN app that works well with single requests, let's say calling `/api/products?pid=500`. But I recently discovered that at a "burst" of requests (i'm updating bulk around 50 products = 50 requests `/api/products?pid=500` *** 550 with post data), the req.body sometimes gets a value of a new upcoming request.

The front app makes the calls in a foreach of selected products:

```
 ds.forEach((d, key) => {
        this.ApiCall.setData('products', { action: 'send-product', data: d })
            .subscribe((result) => {
                //we have results
            });
        });
    //setData makes a http.post().map
```

Back app / mean analyses the post, tried to synthesize the code:

```
router.route('/')
.post(function (req, response) {
    if(req.body.data){
        var obj = { id: req.body.data.product_id }
        if(req.body.data.linked_products){
            req.body.data.linked_products.forEach(function(entry) {
                obj.linked = entry; //more ifs
            });
        }
        var async = require('async');
        async.series({
            q2: function(cb){
                queryProducts.findOne({id: req.body.data.product_id, null).exec(cb);
            },
            q3: function(cb){
                queryCategories.findOne({id: req.body.data.category_id, null).exec(cb);
            }
          }, function(err, qResults){

            var alreadysent = false;
            if (qResults.q3) qResults.q3.logs.forEach(function(entry) {
                if(entry.sent){
                    alreadysent = true;
                }
            });
            //more ifs
            qResults.q3.external_codes.forEach(function(entry) {
                obj.external_code = entry;//more ifs
            });
            if(req.body.data.price < 0){
                response.json({message: "Negative price didn't sent"});
                return;
            }
            if(qResults.q2.status=="inactive"){
                response.json({message: "Inactive didn't sent"});
                return;
            }
            req.body.data.campaigns(function(entry) {
                obj.price_offers = entry;//more ifs
            });
            //more ifs and foreach similar
            queryProducts.update({id: req.body.data.id}, {$push: { synced_products: obj }}, function (err, result) {
                //HERE I found req.body.data with values of a future request

                if(!err)
                    response.json({message: "Sent"});
                return;
            });
        });
    }
});
module.exports = router;
```

I understand that making requests

```
/api/products?pid=500
/api/products?pid=501
/api/products?pid=502
/api/products?pid=503
...
```

have different timings, but how is possible that a request (pid=501), calling the last req.body to have the value of req.body of new req (pid=503)?
Any ideas how to avoid? putting async first right after the post or making a

```
var reqbody = req.body
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. The quoted code (if we assume the missing close paren and semi on the `post` call) shouldn't have any issues with data bleeding across requests, so there's something going on elsewhere.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder sorry, updated the code, thanks!

Comment: Try using `let` instead of `var`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is due to the `async` module initialization.  To quote from the [node docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_caching):

> Caching
>
> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.
>
> Multiple calls to require('foo') may not cause the module code to be executed multiple times. This is an important feature. With it, "partially done" objects can be returned, thus allowing transitive dependencies to be loaded even when they would cause cycles.
>
> To have a module execute code multiple times, export a function, and call that function.

When a burst of requests causes overlapping execution, you will have two (or more) uses of the `async` variable being modified "concurrently".  I would suggest using some sort of mutex to control access to the `async` variable.